# How can I remove a font dowloaded with @font-face from the browser cache?

Tags: css, font-face

Some days ago I made a mistake: I published a new release of my webapp using **@font-face** with a limited version of "Droid Sans" (no Latin characters). The font file are hosted on my server. Now I've changed the font with a full version (most of my customers are Spanish). The new customers get the full font with no problem, but the customers who accessed first time with the limited font don't get the special characters.

I guess the old font is somewhere in the browser cache, but I haven't been able to remove it.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Droid';
src: url(/files/DroidSans.eot);
src: url(/files/DroidSans.eot?iefix) format('eot'),
     url(/files/DroidSans.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/files/DroidSans.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(/files/DroidSans.svg#webfontw7zqO19G) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'DroidBold';
src: url(/files/DroidSansBold.eot);
src: url(/files/DroidSansBold.eot?iefix) format('eot'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBold.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBold.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBold.svg#webfontSOhoM6aS) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body, a, p, div, span, li, td, th, caption {
  font-family: Droid, Optima, Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 14pt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing font name should do the trick, since name is the only criteria for browser to see if font is cached or not cached.

Comment: I've changed both file names and css names, and still get the old font. There must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to force a reload might be adding a nonsense query string to the font URL (or changing the font name as @Silver light suggests, of course! Duh. Didn't think of that).

```
@font-face { font-family:Garamond; src:url(garamond.eot?r=1234567); }
```

This requires of course that the resource in which you have this information gets **reloaded as well**. If it's an external style sheet, you may have to apply the same trick to force it to refresh:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?r=1234567890">
```

Comment: @Francisco if you changed all URLs and it still doesn't work, then the browser must cache fonts on font name level and not *file* name. That would be tough. The only way that might help in that case that I can think of is redirecting users to an entirely new host (e.g. `domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com`)

Comment: Oops, that would be tricky but I'm gonna try. Thanks for the help @Pekka.

Comment: @Francisco you're welcome. No guarantees it'll work, but I assume it should - it wouldn't make sense if the browser would cache fonts globally

Answer (score 1):

change the font name and link in css file.
Because if you configure your server well for static files (etag, cache time), most browsers wont query for newer version of file for long time.

Comment: I've changed both file names and css names, and still get the old font. I can't do much about server configuration since the app is hosted on Heroku.